# Android AdWhirl with AdMob and InMobi

Tags: android, integration, ads, adwhirl, inmobi

Previously I used for Ads just AdMob.
Now I want to use AdWhirl with AdMob and InMobi integration.
AdWhirl with AdMob work fine. But there are no instructions how to integrate AdWhirl and InMobi. Also on [AdWhirlAndroidSDK](https://www.adwhirl.com/doc/android/AdWhirlAndroidSDKSetup.html) there is list of "supported" mobile ad network and among them there is no InMobi. My question is does AdWhirl support InMobi or not? If yes, where can I found working example of AdWhirl + InMobi integration. If no, why is in AdWhirl interface support for InMobi?
Oh, I'm using AdWhirl 3.0.

Comment: at Google IO 2011, AdMob announced that they would be integrating something similar to AdWirl into their core service very soon, I'd wait a little :-)

Comment: Hehe... I don't like that word soon. Still there will be some sort of integration (with other ad networks) which I as a developer need to do.

Comment: Check out: http://goo.gl/kBTog & http://goo.gl/MShlG

Comment: But still I need to implement InMobi with AdWhirl and still don't know how or is it supported at all?

Comment: Yeah hence why I'm writing in a comment. I don't know an answer to your question :-)

Comment: hehe... thx anyway... I really can not wait for google to announce something different and I will still have to do a lot of things

Answer (score 6):

I represent InMobi's Global Ops team and would like to work with you in integrating with InMobi. Can you shoot an e-mail to helpdesk@inmobi.com and I'll work with you to getting this fixed.

Thanks :)

Edit:

For your Android Integration, please use the following methods:

If you are using the SDK source, please replace the InMobi adapter in your source with the file located at the following dropbox linke:
Adwhirl – InMobi Adapter for Android - http://dl.dropbox.com/u/30899852/InMobiAdapter.java

If you are using the compiled SDK Jar from Adwhirl, please use the following jar (exclusively)

Adwhirl Compiled Jar with updated InMobi Adapters - http://dl.dropbox.com/u/30899852/adWhirl/AdWhirlSDK_Android_3.0.0.jar

Please note that this jar is compiled with default adapters which are a part of the SDK source bundle from Adwhirl. The only change is that the InMobi adapter has been updated to work with the new SDK from InMobi. Also note, this is not an official release from Adwhirl but provided by InMobi. I do not represent Adwhirl and only represent InMobi

Hope this helps. As before, please feel free to reach out to us at helpdesk@inmobi.com

AJ